# python-selenium: how to enable load_no_focus_lib

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

When I try to run Firefox from `python-selenium` 2.25.0 on a Ubuntu 14.04.3, I get the following error:

```
Failed to dlopen /usr/lib32/libX11.so.6
```

I did some research ([here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3049) and [there](https://gitlab.com/chrsmith/selenium/issues/591)) and it seems like I have to somewhere set `load_no_focus_lib = False` in a `FirefoxProfile` instance to avoid this error.

But I really can not figure out where nor how…

If someone has the knowledge of what the heck is `x_ignore_nofocus.so` (source code [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py)) and how to use it in `python-selenium`, I would really appreciate your help.